# How to tell the upcomming viewController by which button he was called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sender

I have a viewController, lets say `blaVC`, which calls another view controller `blubbVC` through a button press. As there are 4 buttons, all calling `blubbVC` with the same nib, but the content should vary according to which button was pressed in `blaVC` (content will be loaded from a plist), I'd need `blubbVC` to know *"I've been called, because button A was pressed, so I'll load from the plist with objectForKey:@"button A""* (so to speak..).

I call blubbVC like that

```
- (IBAction) buttonA:(id)sender {
blubbVC *detailView = [[blubbVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"blubbNib" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
[detailView release];
}
```

I tried to pass `sender`, but as I load the content in `initWithNibName`, `sender` comes to late, the content was already loaded (or tried to) and my view stays empty. How would I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you passed your sender BEFORE pushViewController method? At that point view is not loaded, it is loaded after you push it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a function that says takes the sender (or some value representing which button was pressed) that sets up all the state, after it's been initialized.

For example:

```
[detailView setupContent:(id)sender];
```

When you init the view controller, it's not yet displayed. Before you call pushViewController, call the new function, so you'd have:

```
- (IBAction) buttonA:(id)sender {
    blubbVC *detailView = [[blubbVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"blubbNib" bundle:nil];
    [detailView setupContent:sender];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
    [detailView release];
}
```

If it's true that this is too late (you need the data in 'initWithNibName'), then either define your own `-[initWithNibName: andSender:]` or something similar, and  calls `[super initWithNibName:]` before setting up the rest of the state.

Comment: I tried the method call as you described, but it's to late than. I did write my own method as you said. I hadn't had the idea to do it this way.. long day^^ Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom init method in your view controller. Something like:

```
+(id)initWithCaller:(NSString*)caller
{
    if(self == [super initWithNibName:@"blubbNib" bundle:nil]) 
    {
      calledFrom = x;
    }
    return self;
}
```

That was just typing from memory so there may be some errors. You'd then use that new init method in your IBActions

Comment: It is not class method (not +, but -).